# How can I directly invoke an event handler on a route in Emberjs?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I'm hoping to stub/spy on a route's event handler in ember.js using my testing framework of choice, jasmine. Usually this involves overwriting the function of interest with a spy, which requires access to the object on which the method is defined:

```
spy = spyOn(someObject, "methodOnThatObject")
```

But in Ember, my event handlers for my routes are defined as follows:

```
App.ActivityRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  events: {
    show: function(context) {
    }
  }
});
```

I would like to stub the function show, but I don't know how to get the object on which it is eventually defined? Or is it ever defined on an object? Perhaps it's invoked with #call or #apply? If so, how does one stub this?

I've tried digging around the source, but didn't manage to figure out how this is handled. Any pointers to where I should look in the source would also be helpful.

Cheers,
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me. I can just do the following:

```
route = App.__container__.lookup('route:myRoute')
spy = spyOn(route.get('events'), 'show')
controller.send('show')
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

And that works.

Comment: Although beware the events object my go away, as there is an [open issue about this](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/2203) on the ember.js github repo.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `send('eventName', [optional record])`:

If you're calling from a controller under the same route do:

```
this.get('target').send('show', this.get('content'))
```

Comment: I realize that's how to call the function...perhaps my title was misleading...but what I really needed was access to the object on which the event handler was defined. But I figured it out (see my answer). Thanks though!